# How to see the full error message for Safari downloads?

Tags: safari, error, data-transfer

When downloading different things, in Safari, I sometimes get errors. As a developer, seeing the error is helpful to debug and resolve. But it is often cut off and unable to be seen (see below). **How can I see the full error message?**

[image]

**Note:** I am not looking for this specific error message, as I can guess its something like *You do not have permission to access the resource*, but a solution for all future error messages.

Comment: Does rolling your mouse over it work?

Comment: @Panda Nope. :(

Comment: can you redirect us somewhere to reproduce the error ? @JBis

Comment: Is an AppleScript an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @oa- Not really but I guess its better than nothing.

Comment: To reproduce, either start a download that's too big to fit on your drive, or turn off the server part way through the download, or pull the network cable out midway. Produces a variety of frustratingly incomplete error messages!